# How do I re-plot my results against existing results?

Tags: graphics, data

I need to compare my results with other result, so I need to re-plot the other author's results against my results.

For example I want use this fig as a way of comparing results[image]

so is there any way to do that or any software can do that?

Comment: Write a short email to the authors, asking for the data for this plot. I don't say that it will work, but it's certainly worth trying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to about this. The first is to contact the authors of the paper containing th graphs and ask if they can supply the data. Otherwise you can search for digitizing software on the web. I have one (open source) that comes to mind [Engauge Digitizer](http://digitizer.sourceforge.net/) but that is not the only one by far.

Comment: I use  Engauge Digitizer but its not going very well ?

Comment: Two very useful alternatives are *G3Data Graph Analyzer* and *GetData Graph Digitizer*. Both of these are very simple to use, simply set up your axis and select the points. If I remember correctly, GetData even has an algorithm that recognizes the marker shape and grabs them all.

Comment: Here is an example of the microlayer thickness data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qwu6zzljw33lq6f/data.csv